# Is the http.StatusFound the correct status for a click redirect?

Tags: http, redirect, go

I have a simplistic app that needs to take arbitrary input params from a request and then direct the user to the corresponding external location. Is the

> http.StatusFound

the correct response status?

Comment: Yes, that's the normal status for an HTTP redirect.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection for the list of all redirection status codes.

Comment: Thanks! The initial curl request through me off (got a link HTML back). Mind posting as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of different 3xx status codes that are normally associated with redirects, and `302 Found` is one of them. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) for the complete list.

Comment: For completeness, we should mention that `POST` requests should use `303 See Other` or `307 Temporary Redirect`. `GET` requests can continue to use 302.

Comment: @BraveNewCurrency, why?